# Docker Airflow location of airflow config file

Tags: docker, airflow

I installed the official Airflow Docker Image , but I need to find the airflow.cfg file. Where did Docker put this file?
I am using Mac.

Answer (score 1):

use docker-compose and get the entire setup, you need more than the airflow. You will need the UI,flower, etc. Get the docker compose image from:

`https://github.com/puckel/docker-airflow`

Clone the repo and if you look at the `volumes`
https://github.com/puckel/docker-airflow/tree/master/config
in the compose file they map to the config. simply put the files in the config and run the compose. This will save you so much time.